# PHP reset a while() loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I am using the following which basically prints a dropdown box showing all hours with 30 minute increments:

```
$start = '12:00AM';
$end = '11:59PM';
$interval = '+30 minutes';

$start_str = strtotime($start);
$end_str = strtotime($end);
$now_str = $start_str;

echo '<select name="doors_open">';

while($now_str <= $end_str){
    echo '<option value="' . date('h:i A', $now_str) . '">' . date('h:i A', $now_str) . '</option>';
    $now_str = strtotime($interval, $now_str);
}

echo '</select>';
```

BUT, i want to do it twice for another field further down the page... question is, how do I reset the loop?

Here's what I've tried but doesn't work:

```
echo '<select name="event_start">';

reset($now_str);
reset($end_str);
while($now_str <= $end_str){
    echo '<option value="' . date('h:i A', $now_str) . '">' . date('h:i A', $now_str) . '</option>';
    $now_str = strtotime($interval, $now_str);
}

echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reset()` resets the internal cursor of an array. That's a totally different thing than you want to achieve.

You can of course simply duplicate the code, but this neither good code design nor DRY.

The best you can do is to put the whole HTML generation into a helper function:

```
function genSelect($selectName, $start, $end, $interval) {
  $str = "<select name='$selectName'>";

  $start_str = strtotime($start);
  $end_str = strtotime($end);
  $now_str = $start_str;


  while($now_str <= $end_str){
    $str .= '<option value="' . date('h:i A', $now_str) . '">' . date('h:i A', $now_str) . '</option>';
    $now_str = strtotime($interval, $now_str);
  }

  $str .= '</select>';
  return $str;
}
```

Then, you can call it as often as you want:

```
echo genSelect('doors_open', '12:00AM', '11:59PM', '+30 minutes');
```

You may also consider caching the result:

```
$doorsOpenHtml = genSelect('doors_open', '12:00AM', '11:59PM', '+30 minutes');
```

Comment: Would have to add another variable to the function otherwise all would have same name

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I added one.

Comment: Many thanks! Is there a reason to return $str and then echo the function, as opposed to echo $str within the function then just call the function without echo? Just curious

Comment: @DarrenSweeney It might be cleaner to return the string instead of directly echoing it. For instance, what would you do if you need to further process the output of genSelect() (using direct echos)? You would need to use output buffering functions (ob_*) which are quite messy in this case.

Answer (score 3):

In your case you'd just have to reassign the initial value to `$now_str` so your loop can run again. As your `$start_str` variable contains it, you could just reassign it to `$now_str` after the first loop.

```
$now_str = $start_str;
```

The `reset` function actually resets an array internal pointer used for loops, which is not the case here.

Note: I really recommend to use a helper function as @ComFreek recommended to avoid repeating code.

Comment: @ComFreek I'm really sorry for mistyping your name like this, hahaha. It was not proposital.

Comment: No problem, that happens quite often ;)